# Display Nuget packages used

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, nuget

Good morning- I am looking for a way to create view which will display the nuget packages used in my project, including all of the meta data. So far I have the code below, but I cannot get the controller to display the detailed information for each nuget package.

So far I have the following, but it only displays the name of each nuget package and a lot of details I do not need. What I do need are the names and properties of the functions stored in each package. For properties I mean the - parameters needed and any summary information added by the developer.

**View:**

```
<h2>Assemblies</h2>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
      @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)*@ @Html.Raw(item.Description)
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Assemblies()
    { List<GenericList> listAssemblies = new List<GenericList>();            
        string str = string.Empty;
        string properties = "";
        string members = "";
        AssemblyName[] assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
        foreach (AssemblyName item in assemblies)
        {
            //str += item.Name + Environment.NewLine;
            GenericList itemInList = new GenericList();
            itemInList.Name = item.Name;
            itemInList.Description = "<b>CodeBase:</b> " + item.CodeBase
                + "</br><b>ContentType:</b> " + item.ContentType
                + "</br><b>CultureInfo:</b> " + item.CultureInfo
                + "</br><b>CultureName:</b> " + item.CultureName
                + "</br><b>EscapedCodeBase:</b> " + item.EscapedCodeBase
                + "</br><b>Flags:</b> " + item.Flags
                + "</br><b>FullName:</b> " + item.FullName
                + "</br><b>HashAlgorithm:</b> " + item.HashAlgorithm
                + "</br><b>KeyPair:</b> " + item.KeyPair
                + "</br><b>ProcessorArchitecture:</b> " + item.ProcessorArchitecture
                + "</br><b>Version:</b> " + item.Version
                + "</br><b>VersionCompatibility:</b> " + item.VersionCompatibility
                + "</br><b>GetType:</b> " + item.FullName.GetType();
            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                properties += "<h3>Special Properties</h3><b>Name:</b> " + prop.Name 
                    + "</br><b>IsSpecialName:</b> " + prop.IsSpecialName
                    + "</br><b>MemberType:</b> " + prop.MemberType
                    + "</br><b>MetadataToken:</b> " + prop.MetadataToken
                    + "</br><b>PropertyType:</b> " + prop.PropertyType
                    + "</br><b>ReflectedType:</b> " + prop.ReflectedType
                    + "</br><b>SetMethod:</b> " + prop.SetMethod;
                    }
            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetMembers())
            {
                members += "<h3>GetMembers</h3><b>Name:</b> " + prop.Name
                    + "</br><b>MemberType:</b> " + prop.MemberType
                    + "</br><b>MetadataToken:</b> " + prop.MetadataToken
                    + "</br><b>ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName:</b> " + prop.ReflectedType.FullName
                    + "</br><b>Module:</b> " + prop.Module
                    + "</br><b>CustomAttributes:</b> " + prop.CustomAttributes
                    + "</br><b>DeclaringType:</b> " + prop.DeclaringType;
            }
            itemInList.Description += "<div class='float-left divWidth'>" + properties + "</div>" 
                + "<div class='float-left divWidth'>" + members + "</div>";
            listAssemblies.Add(itemInList);
        }
        return View(listAssemblies);
    }
```

**The information I need:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQlWG.jpg)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467988/how-to-get-list-of-packages-of-a-particular-visual-studio-solution-with-nuget-ex) could be one part of your solution.

Comment: That is helpful, but I am looking for a way to show the available classes in each package online. So we can review as a team.