# How to list all installed NuGet Packages and Versions using .NET CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-cli

How to list all locally installed NuGet packages using .NET Core CLI in a ASP.NET Core project without Visual Studio 2017?

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 project.  I have a `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` by default that don't have a Version in it.  I'd like to know what's the Version it used.  I can't find any CLI command to query that information.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467988/how-to-get-list-of-packages-of-a-particular-visual-studio-solution-with-nuget-ex

Comment: @EylM Is it possible not using PowerShell?

Comment: .Net Core CLI doesn't have any command for listing installed Nuget packages for a project. Since `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is a metapackage (set of packages that are meaningful together) you can always check the version of any included package programmatically or manually. You can also check a folder name in `.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.app/[versionNumber]` or use Powershell as was suggested before.

Comment: @RadimGöth It doesn't have any "Version" in the `.csproj` file.  I don't know what's the logic to determine which package version should be applied if there are multiple NuGet packages been installed in the NuGet Packate Store.

Comment: @EylM @RadimGöth I checked the solution.  It just doesn't works.  The PowerShell script only check for `packages.config` and it's content.  It can't be check for package `Version` in the `.csproj` file.  Furthermore is my `.csproj` file don't have a `Version` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If `Version` attribute for metapackage (which `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`is) is not supplied, the lowest locally installed version is taken. You can check which versions you have installed locally in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app`

However, you usually don't want to know metapackage version, but a version of each package in it and you can determine them by:

```
var referencedAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
foreach (var assembly in referencedAssemblies)
   Console.WriteLine($"{assembly.Name} {assembly.Version}");
```

Comment: I do some tests these days.  If `Version` attribute for metapackage (which `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is) is not supplied, it's **not** the lowest locally installed version is taken.  It's aligned with .NET Core SDK `BundledAspNetCoreAllPackageVersion` defined version.  In `2.1.300` which is `2.1.0` by default.